# mongodb where not exists (subtract two query results)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

consider I have the following collection,

```
[

    {
        "user_id": 7,
        "action": 1
    },
    {
        "user_id": 8,
        "action": 1
    },
    {
        "user_id": 9,
        "action": 1
    },
    {
        "user_id": 7,
        "action": 2
    }

]
```

I need to find all users who has for example action 1 but not action 2.
In mysql It's possible to just select user_id with two queries and subtract this results, or use where not exists subquery.

how can I handle this with mongodb?

so my expected result is :

```
[8,9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aggregation pipeline to first group all actions into one array plus the associated user id into objects and the filter to have action `1`, but not `2`, then keep only the id:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // group user id and all actions together
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user_id",
      actions: {
        $addToSet: "$action"
      }
    }
  },
  // filter documents which have 1 as action but not 2
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "actions": 1
        },
        {
          "actions": {
            $not: {
              $eq: 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  // only keep the id
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 8
  },
  {
    "_id": 9
  }
]
```

Here is a link to a playgorund: https://mongoplayground.net/p/So4HjEXx3sn

You should consider how you structure your documents. Your design looks a bit like a relational database. It is advisable to model your documents according to your read accesses (if possible). In this case you could an `user_id` and an `actions` field, which has already all action ids grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and **`$push`** the `actions` for the distinct `user_id`. Finally use **`$match`** with `actions` **`$eq`** ual to 1 but not equal (**`$ne`**) to 2

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user_id",
    "actions": { "$push": "$action" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "actions": { "$eq": 1, "$ne": 2 }}},
  { "$project": { "_id": 1 }
])
```

Comment: thanks, I thinks both answers are correct, so I chose the first answer.

Comment: yes But you don't need to use two `$group` stages here. Simply use `$project` because we already find the distinct `user_id` in the first `$group` stage.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Even that it has less operators. You don't need to use `$group`, `$and`, `$not` aggregation here.